# How to have full-screen background?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a Vue.js app.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <NavBar v-if="showNav"  />
    <b-container fluid class="content">
      <router-view />
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .content {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
</style>
```

In the content I have this Homepage:

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
      <div class="bg-text1" id="block1">
        <b-container class="container2 ">
          <b-row style="margin-left: 10px">
            <h1><b-link
              href="https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-35492-3"
              class="link"
              target="_blank"
              >Web Application of SPIR - Smart Photo Identification
               of the Risso’s dolphin </b-link
            ></h1>
            <h5>
              <p>
                Using this web application of SPIR (see <b-button style="border-radius: 6px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF" variant="danger">Tool</b-button> button), 
                you can automatically photo-identify Risso's dolphins in your photos, using computer vision techniques and advanced statistical strategies. 
              </p>
              <p>
              SPIR description is available in the paper DolFin: an innovative digital platform for studying Risso’s dolphins in the Northern Ionian Sea 
              (North-eastern Central Mediterranean), Scientific Reports, 8, 17185 (2018)
              </p>
            </h5>
          </b-row>
          
          
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .home {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: url("../assets/back4.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  .bg-text1 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

In this way, there is the background-image only where there is text, the other side of the page is white.

I also tried with `position: fixed` for the div `home` and it works, but in this way I can't scroll down if the text overtake the size of the page.

Answer (score 2):

100% for width or height mean 100% of the container (of *.home*). So just use the viewport dimensions **vw** and **vh** since they are independent of the container:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: It works, but the background is white if the text goes over 100vh. Should I repeat the image?

Comment: You could use ```min-height: 100vh;```

Answer (score 1):

In order for height:100%; to work like you want it needs to be placed on all parent elements, all the way up to the html element (or the first parent with a defined height in px).

Here's an example fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g6u3zwq2/15/

I just added this, but you might have more parent elements that need height:100%

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height:100%;
}
```